# Android translate a textView into toolbar subtitle onScoll of a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, toolbar

I am trying to implement an animation where in I want to move a textView which is in the header of a listview and set it as toolbar title when the listview scrolls up. It should start scaling and resizing when the listview starts scrolling up. I hope I am clear. Has anyone done a similar thing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

clarifier i don't understand part header & scrools up  listview

**but this is what u need to use:**

adapter :

- ListAdapter extends Adapter class object

view:

- ListView extends AbsListView class object

  Hrader via ListView as EditText:

  - addHeaderView(View, Object,boolean);
  - removeHeaderView(View);

    Scrolling

    - View.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

      @Override
      onScroll() {    /* remove header */

      }

actionBar:

- Toolbar toolbar = getActionBar(); or getSupportActionBar depends of Activity Class
- title = EditText.getText().toString();
- toolbar.setTitle(String);  or setSubTitle(String) your choice